# How can I alter my image's src on re-size only once if the condition is true, not each time the window is re-sizing?

Tags: jquery, html, regex, resize

I am currently creating a function to grab the image's `src` and then change the src out to a smaller mobile friendly image.

I am trying to make this as dynamic and flexible as possible but for right now I am only testing on one image.

**The problem** is when re-sizing the fiddle, it will keep adding the string of text to the src which ends up breaking it. (The Regex will also not function with an absolute path so I'm not expecting the image to work.)

The path should be:

```
<img src="http://chatfielddrilling.com/Chatfield%20V2/images/home-slide-1-mbl.jpg" alt="overview of building" />
```

But, if the Regex wouldn't replace everything, it would look like:

```
<img src="http://chatfielddrilling.com/Chatfield%20V2/images/home-slide-1-mbl-mbl-mbl-mbl-mbl.jpg" alt="overview of building" />
```

It will just keep adding `-mbl` over and over until the re-sizing stops, also the load function does not seem to work which is odd. (Maybe I can't target `$(window)` for load, I'm still new to scripting)

I am trying to make this flexible by adding the `-mbl` to the end of every image's alt to cut back on the mobile load time but I can't figure out how to stop this.

Here is my jQuery currently:

```
var orgSrc = $('img').attr('src');

$(window).on('load resize', function() { // Resize/load function to change images for mobile phones
    var imgSrc = $('img').attr('src'), // Snags the img's src
        imgPaths = [ 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg' ], // Array of image types
        mobileImg = imgSrc.match(/[^\.]+/) + '-mbl.' + imgPaths[0]; // Dynamically makes the new src for mobile sites

    if ($(window).width() < '800') {
        $('img').attr('src', mobileImg); // If is true then replace with new url
    }
    else {
        $('img').attr('src', orgSrc); // If is not true then replace with old
    }
});
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc3yk/5/)

**I also may be using the Regex wrong**, this is my first time trying to work with it so I apologize if I make a novice mistake.

Comment: Your regex matches from the beginning, why not try matching from the end and up to the first slash?

Comment: I changed it to target the end and this is how it looks on resize, `<img src=".-mbl.jpg" alt="overview of building">`. It does not keep repeating `-mbl` though which is great!

Answer (score 1):

You could specify a true/false flag for when you actually resize. Something along these lines:

```
var orgSrc = $('img').attr('src');

$(window).on('load resize', function() { // Resize/load function to change images for mobile phones
    var imgSrc = $('img').attr('src'), // Snags the img's src
        imgPaths = [ 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg' ], // Array of image types
        mobileImg = imgSrc.match(/[^\.]+/) + '-mbl.' + imgPaths[0], // Dynamically makes the new src for mobile sites
        hasResized = false;

    if(!hasResized) {
        if ($(window).width() < '800') {
            $('img').attr('src', mobileImg); // If is true then replace with new url
            hasResized = true;
        }
        else {
            $('img').attr('src', orgSrc); // If is not true then replace with old
        }
    }    
});
```

That would make it so that your attribute is changed only once, and then you are locked out of that change.  You may have to get a bit more creative if you need to run checks again.

Hope this helps!